# Intercept all Android intents

Tags: android, android-intent, root

I've got an  android phone with root and su access. I'd like to intercept all intents fired by any app and their extras bundles in my android app. Is there a way of doing that without writing a custom aosp ROM? Is it possible to change how Zygote or ActivityManager work?

I know using "adb shell dumpsys" will provide a historical view on past intents but it's missing the intent payload.

I've got a list of all the intents' action names that can be fired and added those to my androidmanfiest.xml. But some are routed to specific packages or limited behind security permissions.

Is there a one-size-fits-all approach that'll intercept all intents in Android?

Comment: I think you're going to have to go custom ROM.  Your application isn't even informed of an Intent if it isn't  possible recipient.

Comment: _"Is it possible to change how Zygote or ActivityManager work?"_ No, unless you customize AOSP. You only can disable those. _"Is there a one-size-fits-all approach that'll intercept all intents in Android?"_ I'd recommend you to at [jtrace](http://newandroidbook.com/tools/jtrace.html), a tool developed by Jonathan Levin aka [@Technologeeks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1734439/technologeeks?tab=profile). Although you might need to do extra efforts to make it work **within an app**.

Comment: @Onik , can you help me with use `jtrace`? I have a problem: 
I use `adb` emulator based x86-64 CPU. I pushed jtrace.x86 on my device ( emulated device) and when I starts it:
`adb shell`; `cd /data/local/tmp` ; `./jtrace` I've got an error: `/system/bin/sh: ./jtrace: No such file or directory`. However, the file exists in fact.

Comment: Yes, I `chmod`ed. When I copy `jtrace` to /system/bin` I got: `cp: /system/bin/jtrace: Read-only file system`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using [Xposed framework](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial)? It basically allows you to intercept any method (such as `Context.startService()`, or any of ActivityManager's) and add your own code.